# how can I start a spring web boot program without parameter args?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a demand that starting the spring boot program without paragram `args` using a swing button.

```
startHttpServerBtn.addActionListener((e)
                -> new Thread(()
                -> BootWebApplication.start()).start());
```

How can i relaize it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your `BootWebApplication` class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and have default `public static void main` method generated by Spring Initializer. 
Then you can easy start Spring Boot app with or without program `args`.
Code example with args:

```
startHttpServerBtn.addActionListener((e)
                -> new Thread(() -> {
        String[] args = new String[1];
        args[0] = "--spring.profiles.active=dev";
        BootWebApplication.main(args)
    }).start());
```

To run without args just pass empty String array: `BootWebApplication.main(new String[0]);`